# datatables header not aligned with columns when scrolling horizontally

Tags: datatables

I cannot figure out the way to solve this. Ive tried adding "table-layout:fixed" but it no longer works in dt's current version.

Thanks

```
var config = {
        "bFilter": false,           
        "bInfo": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
         "scrollY": 200,
         "table-layout":fixed,
        "data": dataoMine, 
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "columns": columns,
        "scroller": true,
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "empty data"
        }, 
        "columnDefs": [
            {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
        ]       
    };
```

[image]

```
<table class="dataTable" style="width:80%; height:100%; margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%;}">
<thead><tr>
    <th>a1</th>
    <th>a2</th> 
    <th>a3</th>
    <th>a4</th>
    <th>a5</th>
    <th>a6</th>
    <th>a7</th>
    <th>a8</th>
</tr></thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle? Here is a starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/819/

Comment: @davidkonrad nothing fancy, just pass the config variable to dt's constructor. that's it

Comment: Can you show the html code for the table?

Comment: @Yuri i've updated the post to include it, thank you

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo the data source would be good also, so maybe you can post a short chunk of your source array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching it turns out that this problem  is very common. It seems there is no definitive solution but this worked for me:

add this into dt's config:

scrollX: 100%

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite have enough information to give you a firm answer, because you don't tell us what's in your `columns` variable and don't give us the structure of your `dataoMine` array.  But, it seems pretty clear from your screen shot that you have four columns of data, and also have eight columns specified.  That will show all the columns and whatever background you have for the missing data columns.  Presumably, your "barbershop stripes" are the page background in whatever theme you are using.

Make sure that you have the same number of columns in your data that you have in your column specification, and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problem by just adding

scrollX: true